# How do object type variables accept class type instance

Tags: c#

I need to clarify a thing that how an object type variables accept class type instance an given in the below code snippet,

```
class MyClass
{

}

static void Main()
{
   object obj = new MyClass();
}
```

Since the MyClass is not a type of object but still the instance of MyClass is accepted in the obj(object) variable.

Comment: Every type inherits from object, so MyClass is a type of object.

Comment: Type in the sense, here it refers to MyClass right? its not derived from object..

Comment: @Sankarann - Why do you think `MyClass` is not derived from `Object`?

Comment: @Sankarann MyClass is implicitly derived from object, cause its the base class for all value and references types

Comment: @Corak: In general case, if we inherit a class means we would use as class MyClass : object -- like this right? but here it is missing.

Comment: @Sankarann Like I said, `every` type inherits from object. You don't explicit define it the way you do in your comment, it happens implicit.

Comment: @Jehof: could it be able to reflect the class to see the implicit inheritance?

Comment: @Sankarann http://ideone.com/ca0epq - Output base type of empty class `MyClass` returns object.

Comment: @Sankarann - Yes, it is missing. That's both a blessing and a curse. Because every Type is derived from `Object`, you don't need to explicitly put `Type : Object` in there. The C# compiler does that automatically for you. (The curse being: if you don't know that, it might cause confusion). I recommend you reading [CLR via C#](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/book.aspx?id=15528) which will give you great insights to what happens "behind the scenes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your class **is** an object.
In C# **all classes** derives from object.

Referring to a class as it's base type is one way of [Polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx).

It might be better understood using an analogy:
Your class **is an** object, like a Dog **is an** animal.

Also, If you try the following:

```
object obj = new MyClass();
bool isMyType = obj == typeof(MyClass);  //<--this will be true.
```

Take a look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080020/what-is-the-real-significanceuse-of-polymorphism) for more information how Polymorphism can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The concept that you do not understand is [polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx) which basically say that you can define an `is` relation between your classes. For a simple logic every dog is an animal so you can have class `Dog` that inherits from `Animal`. This implies that you can assign to variable of type `Animal` an instance of a `Dog` but not the other way around - not every animal is a dog. Another thing is that every thing derives form object this is language concept that you simply can take for granted.

Answer (score 2):

Evrything in c# is derived from [Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173110.aspx)...
even your class.[image]

Answer (score 1):

`.Net` follows `OOPs` (Object Oriented Programming Language) and here every class can act as a object. Every class inherits [Object class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) and hence every class can act as an object. In your example, .Net creates a default constructor to create instance of the class. You can definitely write your own constructor there.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in C# is derived from [Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx).

Even Value Types like struct(int,float,..) are all derived from Object type.

---

When you define your own class,it implicitly derives from the Object type.

It is mentioned in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx)

> All classes, structures, enumerations, and delegates inherit from
>   Object class

Answer (score 1):

MSDN:

**Supports all classes in the .NET Framework class hierarchy and provides low-level
services to derived classes. This is the ultimate base class of all classes 
in the .NET Framework; it is the root of the type hierarchy.**

Inheritance Hierarchy:

**All classes, structures, enumerations, and delegates.**

This means when you use `int.Parse()` to cast some value to `int`, there is a class behind `int` type which makes it able to have methods and do such stuffs. `Object` has been rooted pretty much everywhere in .Net.