# Can anyone describe what is the correct method of dynamic method dispatch of following 2 programmes

Tags: java, oop

```
class B{
    public void p(double i){
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
class A extends B{
    public void p(double i){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}


class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
      //way of using polymorphic 1
        A a=new A();
        a.p(10.0);

      //way of using polymorphic 2
        A a=new B();
        a.p(10.0)
    }
 }
```

Both 2 ways provide same answer.But I want to know what is the difference between these 2 ways of using dynamic polymorphic.what is the best way to use in a program?

Comment: The first example doesn't make use of polymorphism at all, so this appears to be a question of "should I use polymorphism / why use polymorphism / what is polymorphism good for" (ignoring the compiler errors for the time being).

Comment: Related / maybe duplicate: [What is the real significance(use) of polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2080020)

Answer (score 1):

From the context and intent of polymorphism Your second way makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If a method is overridden then in the run time the method of object type will be executed. Not the reference type.