# Overriding the same function for different sub classes is polymorphism?

Tags: polymorphism, overriding

I read somewhere that, overriding is the means by which you get polymorphism. Polymorphism is the ability for an object to vary behavior based on its type.

Now can i just say that when different subclasses override the member of a parent class then it gives me polymorphism?

Also

```
class A
{
public void hello()
{
printf("in A");
}
}

class B extends A
{
public void hello()
{
printf("in B");
}
}

class C extends A
{
public void hello()
{
printf("in C);
}
}
```

Now if i do

```
B b=new B();
C c=new C();
A a1=b;
A a2=c;
a1.hello();
a2.hello();
```

now will a1 use all the members of b those are inherited from A and hence print `in B`; and similarly for a2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Through inheritance, a class can be used as more than one type; it can be used as its own type, any base types, or any interface type if it implements interfaces
**Polymorphism** is important not only to the derived classes, but to the base classes as well. Anyone using the base class could, in fact, be using an object of the derived class that has been cast to the base class type.*

In other words you have polymorphism every time using a base class you can have "different" behaviors.**Overriding** is just a way to have polymorphism but think about interface you don't override any methods but you can still have polymorphism (implementing the interface in different ways)

Answer (score 1):

> I read somewhere that, overriding is the means by which you get
>   polymorphism.

Overriding does not mean Polymorphism. If you override or not still it can be a polymorphism.
Good definition of Polymorphism can be found here: [Polymorphism - Define In Just Two Sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409969/polymorphism-define-in-just-two-sentences/409982#409982)

> Polymorphism is the ability for an object to vary
>   behavior based on its type.

Not necessary. e.g. Animal class has implemented Eat method (via Mouth) and this class has lets say many subclasses. None of the subclass needs to override this method unless they dont eat by mouth.  So subclasses are not implementing Eat method and still can find the polymorphism that Dog *is a* Animal .

> Now can i just say that when different subclasses override the member
>   of a parent class then it gives me polymorphism?

You can say, but just to tell you again, without overriding also we get polymorphism.

```
 YOUR CODE
```

You can try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism is generally ignoring the specific (or derived) knowledge of each class instance, and operating over a collection of base class pointers (or references), letting dynamic dispatch automatically calling the specific overridden derived functions.

The classic example is a `Shape` base class which defines an interface (e.g. one of the functions could be `.area()`), of which we have `Square` and `Circle` derived classes which would both implement their own versions of the `Shape` interface (e.g. each might choose to have their own `.area()` calculations). The if we have a collection of Shape objects, we can operate on them without bothering with specific details:

```
area = 0
for shape in shapes:
    area += shape.area()  # dispatches to specific shape's area() function
```