# what is overriding polymorphism in OOP. Can please give example in php

Tags: php, object-oriented-analysis

I know what is polymorphism. But came accross overriding polymorphism. what is that and when does it needed?

Comment: [This video/playlist](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc&list=PL693EFD059797C21E&index=1) may be helpful

Comment: Maybe you can cite some context in which you came across this term?

Comment: I would read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893907/is-polymorphism-overloading-and-overriding-are-same-concepts). Perhaps giving an example of what you are trying to do would help us clarify things...

Answer (score 1):

### Glad to hear that you know what is "Polymorphism".

Let me explain you what is "**`Overriding`**" in Polymorphism.

Say you have a class called.. **`Bird`**

```
class Bird
{
    public function fly()
    {
        echo "I can fly";
    }
}
```

I have put up a method called `fly()` , which is a common trait for a Bird. (Let's see.. O.o) . I have put up like every bird can fly. Well ok..

Let us have another class called **`Sparrow`** which extends the **`Bird`** class

```
class Sparrow extends Bird
{

}
```

Since it extends the **`Bird`** class, you can directly access the method **`fly()`** like this..

```
$sparrow = new Sparrow();
$sparrow->fly();// "prints" I can fly
```

Well now, Let us have another class called Duck that extends the Bird class (*Assuming... Ducks don't fly*), So we are ought to access the **`fly()`** it would print "I can fly" [We don't need that , so in this case we need to **Override** the method]

### Overriding the method !

```
class Duck extends Bird
{
    public function fly()   //Method Overriding
    {
        echo "I cannot fly";
    }
}
```

Eventually if you do this.. you will get like this..

```
$duck = new Duck();
$duck->fly(); // "prints" I cannot fly
```

---

### This is somewhat a basic explanation of "Method Overriding".

Comment: 1) A duck *can* fly very well. 2) A bird which cannot fly should not `extend` one that can. The class hierarchy should be `Bird`, `FlyingBird extends Bird`, `Sparrow extends FlyingBird`, `Kiwi extends Bird`. Or use interfaces. ;)