# How do I specify which constructor of a class I want to call?

Tags: java

I'm creating a defined amount of objects from another class, and attempting to randomize the color for each one using java.awt.Color.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numBalls; i++){       
    ballsInSim.add(
        new BoxBall(
            0,
            0,
            (int) boxWidth,
            (int) boxHeight,
            rng.nextInt(35) + 15,
            rng.nextInt(500) + 25,
            rng.nextInt(500) + 25,
            Color.BLUE, // Create new Colour here using constructor
            myCanvas
        )
    );
}
```

Where `Color.BLUE` currently is, I'd like to call one of Color's constructors that uses three integers for the red, green, and blue values (Color(int r, int g, int b)).

How do I call that constructor?  I am relatively new to Java and I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around this.

Comment: replace Color.BLUE with new Color(r,g,b).  r, g, and b can be fields that you set, such as:  Random rand = new Random();  float r = rand.nextFloat();

Comment: That could very well be it.  I forgot to type the 'new' keyword.  Rookie mistake.  I'll edit my code and post what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want, simply add the following:

```
new Color(0, 0, 255)
```

So in essence, it will look like this:

```
ballsInSim.add(new BoxBall(0, 0, (int) boxWidth, (int) boxHeight, rng.nextInt(35) + 15, rng.nextInt(500) + 25, rng.nextInt(500) + 25, new Color(0, 0, 255), myCanvas));
```

In order to achieve random colors each time:

```
Random R = new Random(256);
Random G = new Random(256);
Random B = new Random(256);

//your color constructor will then be:
new Color(R.nextInt(), G.nextInt(), B.nextInt());
```

To know more about the Color Class, refer to this: [Color: Java 7](https://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Fawt%2FColor.html&ei=XgA0VfuaPJHtauHmgJAC&usg=AFQjCNHPDbAtjIFAA8B3xBzpklmWTbuo9g&sig2=i4-htD-1K0Fn_rmsFtyDiA&bvm=bv.91071109,d.d2s)

Hope this helps

Comment: would that not be `Random(256)`?

Comment: I'm most likely only going to use one Random object and call it for each value I want.  For example:

`Random rn = new Random();
int r = rn.nextInt(255);'

Comment: @TejjD "Flexibility"? You mean that the random numbers are a bit *randomer*? In the current form, the code is plainly *wrong*.

Comment: @soltk You should definitely use `nextInt(256)`. Otherwise (with `nextInt()`), you'd quickly receive an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 1):

If you call the constructor with the arguments you want the compiler will select the correct one.

Comment: actually this definition is wrong
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893907/is-polymorphism-overloading-and-overriding-are-same-concepts

Comment: I find it interesting that Overloading is not considered polymorphic, but a sentence later it is called static polymorphism. It is an interesting way of looking at it. I'll update the answer

Comment: I have tried doing that.  It gives me a "cannot find the method specified".  I made sure that I imported the Color class and wrote the Constructor correctly.

Comment: It could be that you have the wrong Color class. It's probably worth while posting the whole piece of code showing the imports

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the actual question: There are multiple constructors for `Color`. Some of them only differ in the argument type, namely these:

```
Color(float r, float g, float b)
Color(int r, int g, int b)
```

When you call

```
Color c = new Color(r,g,b);
```

the question about which constructor will be called is actually a bit tricky: It depends on the type of the given arguments. For details, you may refer to the [Section 15.9.3. Choosing the Constructor and its Arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.3) of the Java Language Specification.

However, in this case, you can make it simple: If you pass in three `float` values, then the `float` version will be called. If you pass in three `int` values, then the `int` version will be called.

Concerning the implementation: If your intention is to create random colors, I'd recommend creating a small helper method:

```
private static final Random COLOR_RANDOM = new Random(0);

private static Color createRandomColor() {
    int r = COLOR_RANDOM.nextInt(256);
    int g = COLOR_RANDOM.nextInt(256);
    int b = COLOR_RANDOM.nextInt(256);
    return new Color(r,g,b);
}
```

Then, you can simply call this method everywhere, for example...

```
for (int i = 0; i < numBalls; i++)
{       
    ballsInSim.add(new BoxBall(0, 0, (int) boxWidth, (int) boxHeight,
        rng.nextInt(35) + 15, rng.nextInt(500) + 25, rng.nextInt(500) + 25, 
        createRandomColor(),  // <---- ... here!
        myCanvas));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's rather simple, Java picks the constructor to use based on the arguments you supply to the constructor. In case of Color you have 7 options as you can see below:

```
Color(ColorSpace cspace, float[] components, float alpha)
```

Creates a color in the specified ColorSpace with the color components specified in the float array and the specified alpha.

```
Color(float r, float g, float b)
```

Creates an opaque sRGB color with the specified red, green, and blue values in the range (0.0 - 1.0).

```
Color(float r, float g, float b, float a)
```

Creates an sRGB color with the specified red, green, blue, and alpha values in the range (0.0 - 1.0).

```
Color(int rgb)
```

Creates an opaque *sRGB* color with the specified combined RGB value consisting of the red component in bits 16-23, the green component in bits 8-15, and the blue component in bits 0-7.

```
Color(int rgba, boolean hasalpha)
```

Creates an *sRGB* color with the specified combined RGBA value consisting of the alpha component in bits 24-31, the red component in bits 16-23, the green component in bits 8-15, and the blue component in bits 0-7.

```
Color(int r, int g, int b)
```

Creates an opaque sRGB color with the specified red, green, and blue values in the range (0 - 255).

```
Color(int r, int g, int b, int a)
```

Creates an *sRGB* color with the specified red, green, blue, and alpha values in the range (0 - 255).

If you supply three *ints*, the last one will be used. In case of three *floats* it will be the third one.

#### In your case all you have to do is replace `Colour.BLUE` with:

```
new Colour(
    new Random().nextInt(256),
    new Random().nextInt(256),
    new Random().nextInt(256),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're after [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28float,%20float,%20float%29), then

```
new Color(r, g, b)
```

is instantiating the class using that constructor, where `r`, `g` and `b` are variables / fields that correspond to red, green and blue.

Comment: I forgot the 'new' keyword.  Rookie mistake.  However,  I'm after the constructor that uses integers instead of floating point decimals.  It should work the same.

Comment: @soltk Then just use that one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int, int, int%29

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
ballsInSim.add(new BoxBall(0, 0, (int) boxWidth, (int) boxHeight, rng.nextInt(35) + 15, rng.nextInt(500) + 25, rng.nextInt(500) + 25, new Color(r, g, b), myCanvas));}
```

where `r, g, b` are previously defined random integers from 0 to 255;