# Is overriding a type of polymorphism?

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism, design-principles

After reading [**this article**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx), it seems to me that overriding is a type of polymorphism, at least in C# programming.(Not speaking of java but about general programming)

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it's a type of polymorphism (runtime polymorphism) if you are talking about C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Polymorphism vs Overriding vs Overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading) and/or [Is Polymorphism , Overloading and Overriding are same concepts?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12893907/3425536)

Comment: @zenith, unless OP clarifies which language he is targeting, the linked post it's a duplicate since it's targeting for Java.

Answer (score 2):

Polymorphism can be achieved by using two ways.

Those are :

- [**Method overriding**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding#C.2B.2B)
- [**Method overloading**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading)