# does overloading not come under polymorphism?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

I have studied from our mentors and books that `polymorphism` means having many `shapes` and in java it is achieved by two ways.

- `overloading`
- `overriding`.

in oracle docs [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) in defined very well. but i don't understand why they have not defined overloading under polymorphism they have discussed only overriding? I guess by the means many shapes overloading should also come under polymorphism.

I have already gone through all the questions but i m not clear from these answers because everyone have stated their views without any reference, everyone have different views some are saying yes others are saying no without justification.

[image: Java The Complete reference 8th ed]

I think the highlighted portion (referenced from `Java The Complete reference 8th ed`) is written example of `overloading`.
Then how everyone says overloading has nothing todo with ovrloading but overriding?

```
that how polymorphism is not achieved by overloading?
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893907/is-polymorphism-overloading-and-overriding-are-same-concepts

Comment: Overloading has nothing to do with polymorphism.

Comment: comon @all who have marked it duplicate, I am not satisfied with the answers that's why i asked it here.

Comment: If you are not satisfied with the answers or the suggested duplicate then you need to explain what else you want to known. The people who might be able to answer are not mind readers and are unlikely to guess what else you want.

Comment: @AdrianHHH my question is clear enough if you have read it completely not only the title,

Comment: Your question may be clear but it has been marked as a duplicate by people who understand the issues. I just commented to say that if you wish those experts to look again at your question then you need to explain which aspects of the question have not been covered by the suggested duplicate. My comment was intended to help you to get the information you want. The edit you made to say your question has not been answered gives no guidance to the experts on why you say your question has not been answered. My knowledge of the topic is not enough to add any extra answers.

Answer (score 0):

"Overloading" is the term for having multiple variants of a method *in the same class*. For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public String doStuff()
    { return this.doStuff( "stuff" ) ; }

    public String doStuff( String sStuff )
    { return this.doStuff( sStuff, "things" ) ; }

    public String doStuff( String sStuff, String sWith )
    { return "Do " + sStuff + " with " + sWith + "." ; }
}
```

The `Foo` class provides three variants of the `doStuff()` method: one with no arguments, one with a single argument, and one with two arguments. It's common for overloading to look like this, where most variants of the method actually just call the next-higher-complexity method with some default value.

This allows you to have predictable behavior with any of zero, one, or two arguments:

```
Foo foo = new Foo() ;
System.out.println( foo.doStuff() ) ;                    // "Do stuff with things."
System.out.println( foo.doStuff( "stuff" ) ) ;           // "Do stuff with things."
System.out.println( foo.doStuff( "more stuff" ) ) ;      // "Do more stuff with things."
System.out.println( foo.doStuff( "stuff", "things" ) ) ; // "Do stuff with things."
System.out.println( foo.doStuff( "things", "stuff" ) ) ; // "Do things with stuff."
```

By contrast, "overriding" is a principle of polymorphism in which a descendant class changes the behavior of a method from the superclass.

```
public class Bar extends Foo
{
    @Override
    public String doStuff( String sStuff )
    { return this.doStuff( sStuff, "thingamabobs" ) ; }
}
```

Comment: @OAD Also, for the sake of comparison, PHP, unlike Java, does not allow overloading, but it does allow default parameter values, which can give you similar behavior.

Comment: You shouldn't write your code like `{ /* stuff */ }` in one line.  This is harder to read and not worth the few lines you save with that.

Comment: @zerobandwidth see update of question

Comment: @OAD That still describes overriding and class hierarchy in general, not overloading. The plain word "polymorphism" applies to anything that can take different forms, but in OOP (esp. Java) it refers to the relationship between descendant classes. In the above example `Foo` is a single class that provides different ways to access the basic function `doStuff()`, whereas `Bar` "is a `Foo`" but is also something else. It's _that_ variability of form that's described by the technical "polymorphism".

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism is a very general term, it can be achieved in many ways in Java and can be comprised of few or many components.

The link you provided lists polymorphism as an aspect of *inheritance* in Java. While `overloading` falls under the polymorphism notion, `overriding` is much more relevant in achieving polymorphism through inheritance in Java.