# Is this polymorphism (C++ / Procedural way of programming)?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I wonder if this is an example of polymorphism in c++. I checked examples in OOP but I didn't find any in pure procedural way of programming. 
Thank you in advance for your answers!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int return_value(int a) {
return 5;
}
char return_value(char b) {
return 'a';
}
int main() {
    int a = 1;
    char b = 'c';
    cout << return_value(a);
    cout << return_value(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it isn't polymorphism.

Comment: That isn't polymorphism; it's *overloading*. There is an entire web of examples of polymorphism out there; all it takes is looking.

Comment: I found a lot of examples of course... But I didn't know if my example is example of polymorphism... Based on the explanation (one of many) that one function can have many shapes... It could be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymorphism means one name many forms.
In that sense even the function overloading is a kind of polymorphism, as same name provides you different functionalities.

Some categorize polymorphism as Compile-time polymorphism & Run-time polymorphism. The function overloading then is a case of Compile-time polymorphism. The virtual functions are example of runtime polymorphism.

So yes, your code is an example of compile-time polymorphism.

For more details on differences between runtime and compile-time polymorphism, See [What is the difference between dynamic and static polymorphism in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783266/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-static-polymorphism-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

That's just an overloaded function, it could be considered polymorphism in some way.
But, here you can find something more about polymorphism:

[Polymorphism in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854581/polymorphism-in-c)

Comment: Thank you! Based on the article you've suggested I can assume that the answer on my question is YES =)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a polymorphism, [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/polymorphism-in-c/) you may found polymorphism and its variations .

Comment: @JanezMurn Overloading means creating methods with same name but different parameters. Overriding means re-defining body of a method of superclass in a subclass to change behavior of a method. Polymorphism is a wide concept which includes overriding and overloading and much more in it's scope. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893907/are-polymorphism-overloading-and-overriding-similar-concepts)

Answer (score 0):

This could be considered as compile time polymorphic. An example for run time polymorphism is using virtual functions in base class and override those functions in the extended class.