# PhoneGap AppDelegate MainViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, inheritance, cordova

I setup a PhoneGap application and dug around some of the code. Under AppDelegate there is the following object:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet CDVViewController* viewController;
```

However, further down there is this line:

```
self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
```

What does that line actually do, as viewController is a CDVViewController object, however it now seems to be saying, or at least converting it to a MainViewController object.

Also MainViewController inherits CDVViewController so whats the point should it not begin as a MainViewController like:

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MainViewController* viewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't begin as  `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MainViewController* viewController` so that when self.viewController responds to a message's selector, self.viewController can be either class CDVViewController or MainViewController, depending on which responds to the selector at runtime.

This is called polymorphism. You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409969/polymorphism-define-in-just-two-sentences) or [this](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/polymorphism-is-always-wrong-word.html).

Comment: How would I then set a property of MainViewController using self.viewController, currently trying self.viewController.token = @"hello", results in an error saying self.viewController is a CDVViewObject and so no such property exists :S

Comment: If you look at CDVViewObject's property, I assume there's no "token" declared. The power of polymorphism is in the implementation of functions, and how they behave at runtime.