# Correlating Java features with Wikipedia's definition of Polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading, overriding

Wikipedia states that there are 3 (major) types of Polymorphism. Correlating this definition with my limited understanding of Java Polymorphism, this is the mapping I came up with -

1. Adhoc polymorphism - Java Function Overloading (dynamic dispatch).
2. Parametric polymorphism - Java Generics.
3. Subtyping - Java Function Overriding (static dispatch).

Is this correct?

References - 
 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29
 2. [Polymorphism - Define In Just Two Sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409969/polymorphism-define-in-just-two-sentences)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ad-hoc polymorphism would map to method overloading (where the method is already known at compile time)
2. is correct
3. Subtyping would map to to overriding (dynamic dispatch)

Comment: Subtyping is not restricted to functions/methods. It's more a fundamental property of Java's OO paradigma itself: ["If S is a subtype of T... any term of type S can be safely used in a context where a term of type T is expected"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping).

Comment: I have to disagree with your interpretation of 1. and 3. - Ad-hoc polymorphism [maps to *overloading*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism), not overriding which is just *not* known at compile time. And subtyping is just the way Java enforces it's type safety in general, see my other comment.

Comment: yes I have really confused them, sorry, quite embarrassing, I would have deserved a downvote as well :S

Answer (score 1):

1. correct.
2. correct.
3. Subtyping - In general, that's how Java's inheritance works, irrespective of methods or fields or parameter types.