# Failure to choose a right overload for method called from a generic method

Tags: java, generics, overloading

I have a following code:

```
class A{}
class B{}
class StuffDoer {
  public void doStuff(A a) { System.out.println("A"); }
  public void doStuff(B b) { System.out.println("B"); }
  public void doStuff(Object o) { System.out.println("Object"); }
}

class Test {
  private final StuffDoer stuffDoer;

  public <T> void foo(T t) {
    stuffDoer.doStuff(t)
  }
}
```

And following execution

```
Test test = new Test();
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
test.foo(a);
test.foo(b);
```

prints "Object" twice, instead of expected "A" and "B" afterwards.

It doesn't work if i explicit pass a Class object either

```
class Test {
  private final StuffDoer stuffDoer;

  public <T> void foo(T t) { //doesnt work
    stuffDoer.doStuff(t.getClass().cast(t))
  }

  public <T> void foo(T t, Class<T> tClass) { //doesnt work either
    stuffDoer.doStuff(tClass.cast(t))
  }

}
```

It only works if i explicity cast them to proper object in the foo method like this

```
class Test {
  private final StuffDoer stuffDoer;

  public <T> void foo(T t) {
    if ( t instanceof A ) 
      stuffDoer.doStuff((A) t) // Prints "A"
    else if ( t instance of B ) 
      stuffDoer.doStuff((B) t) // Prints "B"
    else
      stuffDoer.doStuff(t) // Prints "Object"
  }
}
```

Why is that? How can i achive right method overloading from a generic type? Is it even possible in Java?

Comment: At runtime T gets erased to Object when you don't specify a bound. getClass() returns the runtime type.

Comment: But when i print tClass object it shows me a true type

Comment: Think about how you would have to call your method that has the tClass argument. `test.foo(b, B.class);` You're passing a class literal.

Comment: And even then it is not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overloading in Java and multiple dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759141/overloading-in-java-and-multiple-dispatch) [Overloaded method selection based on the parameter's real type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1572403/1689608)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java only the `method receiver` is picked dynamically at runtime whereas the signature of a method is determined at compile time using the provided argument type(s), so that `doStuff(Object o)` method is being chosen as the only possible (commenting it out would result in a compile-time error).

There aren't many options around to "emulate" multiple dispatch in the way you want:

- A chain of `instanceof` as you already mentioned
- A Visitor/Strategy pattern
- Dynamic method lookup via Reflection or `MethodHandle`
- Pattern matching (since Java 17):

  ```
  public <T> void foo(T t) {
      switch (t) {
          case A a  -> stuffDoer.doStuff(a);
          case B b  -> stuffDoer.doStuff(b);
          case null -> System.out.println("OOPS :(");
          default   -> stuffDoer.doStuff(t);
      }
  }
  ```