# C# Polymorphism

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Try to describe polymorphism as easy as you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210460/try-to-describe-polymorphism-as-easy-as-you-can)

I have trouble understanding what exactly polymorphism is?
And for example how would this code use polymorphism

I have a car class and a method inside that called countprice and i also have a jeep class that inherits from the car class.

```
List<Car> carlist = new List<Car>();
Jeep jeepABC123 = new Jeep(800, 14, 20, 10, 3500);
carlist.Add(jeepABC123);
Sedan sedanGHA321 = new Sedan(600, 7, 20, 10);
carlist.Add(sedanGHA321)

// This code
foreach (Bil bil in carlist)
{
revenue = revenue + car.countprice();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a dup. Read the post linked to by Alastair and if there is still something you don't understand then reformulate your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, you can put `Jeep`s into your array of `Car`s

Maybe you can also implement `Truck` which would inherit from `Car`, then your `carlist` can have both `Jeep`s and `Truck`s in it at the same time.

Polymorphism means that you can put any derived class into a variable declared for the base class, and it's a very fundamental concept of object-oriented programming.

I first truly appreciated polymorphism when I started writing simple games.

for instance:

```
foreach(Enemy enemy in Enemies)
{
    enemy.update();
}
```

each of those `update` calls can do something different, one can cause the enemy to shoot at you, where another can cause the enemy to change it's position, but they all have an update call, and all the update calls have the same signature.

Comment: So In my case would revenue = revenue + car.countprice(); apply to my jeep class?

Comment: @Benny you did put a `Jeep` in `carlist` did you not?

Comment: Yes i did =) I think i understand now