# Casting an object to a Type and use a method

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

Let's say i have an abstract class ObjectA. ObjectC and ObjectB inherit from ObjectA. There are a lot more that inherit from ObjectA.

Then, I have methods that do something according to the type of the object.

```
public void DoSomething(ObjectC data){}
public void DoSomething(ObjectB data){}
```

I was wondering if there's a way to call the method that i need according to the type of the object, that's because i don't know what kind of Object i will get.

```
public void DoSomething(ObjectA data){
    DoSomething(data);
}
```

Currently i am using

```
public void DoSomething(ObjectA data){
    if (data is ObjectB dataB){
        DoSomething(dataB);
    }else if (data is ObjectC dataC){
        DoSomething(dataC);
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there's a way to avoid the usage of a `if/else`.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Try to describe polymorphism as easy as you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210460/try-to-describe-polymorphism-as-easy-as-you-can)

Comment: Hi @Asdren, I think that you're talking about polymorphism, please check the link I posted

Comment: Of course! Using Interfaces. I'll provide an example in a minute

Comment: With generics you can create a method, and use for many many objects that you don't know about that.

Comment: Is `DoSomething` a virtual or overridable method to `ObjectA`?

Comment: @RickDavin No, it is a method in a different class.

Comment: @Asdren: I updated my answer.  I think it now fully answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `is` operator and casting.
Check out:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/uvjHHV

```
using System;

public class Program
{

    public abstract class ObjectA { }

    public class ObjectB : ObjectA {}

    public class ObjectC : ObjectA {}

    public static void Main()
    {
        // You may get this instance from anywhere
        Object o = new ObjectB();

        if (o is ObjectB) 
            DoSomething((ObjectB) o);
        else if (o is ObjectC)
            DoSomething((ObjectC) o);

    }


    public static void DoSomething(ObjectB o) {
        Console.WriteLine("Object B called");   
    }

    public static void DoSomething(ObjectC o) {
        Console.WriteLine("Object C called");   
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you intend for `o` to be declared as `Object` or did you mean for it to be `ObjectA`?  It works in either case, but I think `ObjectA` is better.

Comment: In the fiddle is `ObjectA`, I changed to `Object` just to show that it can be literally any object.

Comment: This is one way to do it, but the if / else is unfortunate.

Comment: If `DoSomething` is not a member function from `ObjectA` there is no other way of doing it... You have to check what type you are receiving with `if/else` somewhere...

Comment: That's the way it is implemented right now, the problem is, there are a lot of types so there are a lot of `if/else`.

Comment: @Asdren, again: if `DoSomething` is not a member function, as @Flydog57 described on his answer, there isn't other way to do it that you wouldn't have to check for the types with `if/else` somewhere. If you make `DoSomething` part of the `ObjectA` class, then you can use override and polymorphism to achieve it. Just like the answer from Flydog.

Comment: Actually, maybe you could use some really ugly reflection to iterate through your functions and calling the right one. But this is so not recommended I wont even write an example... n_n'

Comment: If you are going to do this in this fashion, you can use the new form of `switch`.  Find the latest docs on `switch` and search for "Pattern Matching" on types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching.  It reads a lot better than a cascading series of `else if` statements.  It's also less prone to mis-typed errors

Comment: You **don't** have to use multiple if / else... @Asdren did you check out my solution?

Comment: @Yusha, I don't see how your answer solves the problem... Its not about having various `DoSomething`, it's about knowing which one to call... Your answer does not address this...

Answer (score 3):

The traditional way to do this is to invert what you are asking and to use `virtual` functions to implement `polymorphism` in the fashion described by @RuiJarimba in the comments.  For example, consider these three classes (I renamed your ObjectX classes to ClassX):

```
public abstract class ClassA
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        //Do something that is ClassB specific
    }
}

public class ClassC : ClassA
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        //Do something that is ClassC specific
    }
}
```

Every instance of `ClassB` and `ClassC` is inherently a `ClassA` (through inheritance).  Both `ClassB` and `ClassC` implement a `DoSomething` method that overrides the abstract definition that `ClassA` has defined.  Now, I can take any `ClassA` object (which has to be an instance of a sub-class of `ClassA` since `ClassA` is abstract) and call `DoSomething()` on it and get a class-specific implementation of `DoSomething()`.  In the code below, I create separate instances.  In real life, you normally have a collection of `ClassA` object references that you walk through calling appropriate methods:

```
   ClassA objectB = new ClassB();
   ClassA objectC = new ClassC();

   objectB.DoSomething();      //calls ClassB's version
   objectC.DoSomething();      //calls ClassC's version
```

It's not exactly what you are asking about, but I think it's what you want.

### Continuing On

If you want to keep that same function signature, you can add the following to the `ClassA` definition:

```
  public static void DoSomething<T>(T data) where T : ClassA
  {
      data.DoSomething();     //dispath through the right class using a virtual function
  }
```

If you do that, then this will work (using the `objectB` and `objectC` instances created above:

```
    ClassA.DoSomething(objectB);      //calls ClassB's version
    ClassA.DoSomething(objectC);      //calls ClassC's version
```

What the new code does is take the object it is passed (which is necessarily an instance of a `ClassA` subclass) and simply calls the previously defined virtual function, dispatching things to the appropriate class's implementation.

Comment: This isn't a bad solution either but who wants to keep creating new objects to call eeach method?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following.  The traditional example of this is `abstract class Shape` with concrete classes like `Rectangle`, `Circle`, etc. with a method named `Draw`.  You write a program that allows instantiation of various kind of shape objects, and your draw routine just walks the list and lets each shape draw itself. If you look at the OP's question, he has two objects (one an `ObjectB`, the other an `ObjectC`), each called `data`.  He does something to each one.  If you don't have multiple objects of different types, the question is moot.