# polymorphism relates inheritance

Tags: polymorphism

why polymorphism is dependent on inheritance? code example?

Comment: Do you know what is inheritance?

Comment: Reading your question title I assume you want to know 'How Polymorphism is related to Inheritance?'.

Answer (score 11):

Polymorphism is **not** inherently dependent on inheritance.

Polymorphism is a rather abstract concept about giving uniformous **interfaces** to different kinds of **values**.

In common object-oriented languages like Java or C#, these interfaces are provided through class inheritance, but this is *one possible implementation of polymorphism* and not the concept of polymorphism in general.

Duck typing, structural typing, C++-style templates or typeclasses all provide other implementations of polymorphism.

Just see all this polymorphous codes in order to provide an interface to ducks ...

[Inheritance/Interfaces (C#):](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28computer_science%29)

```
interface Duck { void quak(); }

void DoQuak(Duck d) { d.quak(); }
```

[Dynamic Duck-typing (Python):](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)

```
def DoQuak(d):
    d.quak();
```

[Templates (Static duck-tying) (C++):](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_template)

```
template <typename T>
void DoQuak(const T& d) { d.quak(); }
```

[Structural types (Scala):](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_typing)

```
def DoQuak(d : { def quak() : Unit }) { d.quak() }
```

[Type classes (Haskell):](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class)

```
class Quakable a where
    quak :: a -> IO ()

doQuak d = quak d
```

Comment: A-god-damned-MEN!  I'm tired of people thinking there's something special about OOP languages that makes them the only source of polymorphism!

Add Modula-3's generics (which are different from C++ templates in important ways) to the list.  Or Eiffel's generics, for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism is the ability for an object to vary behavior(behave differently) based on its type.

Overriding is the means by which you achieve polymorphism. An override function "replaces" a function inherited from the base class.

This part of SO has a [discussion/examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading) that might interest you further.

Answer (score 0):

Providing your interfaces match you don't *need* to use inheritance.

It's easier to ensure interfaces match and provide a guarantee by using a contract such as subclassing a base class that has abstract methods (that you *have* to provide an  implementation for in your subclass) or implement a shared interface.

Interfaces don't contain any code, they're just what they say on the tin - a blueprint for a certain interface. Base classes can contain some implementation but abstract classes and methods **must** be derived / subclassed to be used.

Then you can apply type hints to check for a common Interface or base class (Observer):

```
public function register(Observer observer) {

    observers.push(observer);

}
```

or check an Interface is implemented:

```
if (class instanceof MyInterface) {
    // call a method that exists in your interface
    class.myMethod();
}
```

or your object extends a base-class that has certain abstract methods:

```
if (class instanceof MyBaseClass) {
    class.guaranteedToExist();
}
```