# When do I use super()?

Tags: java, inheritance, super

I'm currently learning about class inheritance in my Java course and I don't understand when to use the `super()` call?

Edit:
I found this example of code where `super.variable` is used:

```
class A
{
    int k = 10;
}

class Test extends A
{
    public void m() {
        System.out.println(super.k);
    }
}
```

So I understand that here, you must use `super` to access the `k` variable in the super-class. However, in any other case, what does `super();` do? On its own?

Comment: Actually, in this example `super` is not required to reference `k`.  `k` can be referenced directly.  `super` would only be required to access `A.k` if you declared another field named `k` in `Test` (`Test.k`).

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Calling *exactly* `super()` is **always** redundant.  It's explicitly doing what would be implicitly done otherwise.  That's because if you omit a call to the super constructor, the no-argument super constructor will be invoked automatically anyway.  Not to say that it's bad style; some people like being explicit.

However, where it becomes useful is when the super constructor takes arguments that you want to pass in from the subclass.

```
public class Animal {
   private final String noise;
   protected Animal(String noise) {
      this.noise = noise;
   }

   public void makeNoise() {
      System.out.println(noise);
   }
}

public class Pig extends Animal {
    public Pig() {
       super("Oink");
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose a method is overriden in a child class and then again overriden in its child class. ( Multilevel Inheritance) What if we have to call a method of the grandparent and the parent simultaneously into the grandchildren class. How would the super be used?

Comment: @h8pathak: If you're asking how a child class can bypass its parent's implementation but call the grandparent, that's not possible in Java.

Answer (score 45):

`super` is used to call the `constructor`, `methods` and `properties` of parent class.

Answer (score 25):

You may also use the `super` keyword in the sub class when you want to invoke a method from the parent class when you have overridden it in the subclass.

**Example:**

```
public class CellPhone {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("I'm a cellphone");
    }
}

public class TouchPhone extends CellPhone {
    @Override
    public void print() {
        super.print();
        System.out.println("I'm a touch screen cellphone");
    }
    public static void main (strings[] args) {
        TouchPhone p = new TouchPhone();
        p.print();
    }
}
```

Here, the line `super.print()` invokes the `print()` method of the superclass `CellPhone`. The output will be:

```
I'm a cellphone
I'm a touch screen cellphone
```

Comment: was it (String[] args) in your main method declaration line? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11):

You would use it as the first line of a subclass constructor to call the constructor of its parent class.

For example:

```
public class TheSuper{
    public TheSuper(){
        eatCake();
    }
}

public class TheSub extends TheSuper{
    public TheSub(){
        super();
        eatMoreCake();
    }
}
```

Constructing an instance of `TheSub` would call both `eatCake()` and `eatMoreCake()`

Answer (score 9):

When you want the super class constructor to be called - to initialize the fields within it.  Take a look at this article for an understanding of when to use it:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: As it says in the link, you never *have* to call `super()`, as Java will implicitly add it.  But you do have to call `super(args)` if you need a non-default parent constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You could use it to call a superclass's method (such as when you are overriding such a method, super.foo() etc) -- this would allow you to keep that functionality and add on to it with whatever else you have in the overriden method.

Answer (score 1):

Super will call your parent method. See: http://leepoint.net/notes-java/oop/constructors/constructor-super.html

Comment: Your link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

You call `super()` to specifically run a constructor of your superclass. Given that a class can have multiple constructors, you can either call a specific constructor using `super()` or `super(param,param)` oder you can let Java handle that and call the standard constructor. Remember that classes that follow a class hierarchy follow the "is-a" relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your subclass' constructor must be a call to `super()` to ensure that the constructor of the superclass is called.

Comment: Not true.  It'll happen automatically.

Comment: Even if there's no default constructor? How will it know what to pass?

Comment: If there's no default constructor, you need to call `super(some args)`, not `super()`.  But the point is, "must" is wrong.  One of the super class's constructors is **guaranteed** to be called as long as the class compiles.

Comment: I didn't make it clear that when I wrote super() I didn't mean a constructor with no parameters, I just didn't feel like writing any. And yes I meant you needed to call it or it won't compile, that's why I said must.

Comment: Once again, you do NOT need an explicit call to a super constructor if there exists a no-arg constructor in the parent class.  A super constructor will **always** be called, whereas your phrasing makes it sound like you're in danger of a super constructor not being called if you don't put `super(...)` in.  There is absolutely no danger of that; just danger that it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

From oracle documentation [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html):

> If your method overrides one of its superclass's methods, you can invoke the overridden method through the use of the keyword `super`.

You can also use `super` to refer to a hidden field (although hiding fields is discouraged).

Use of `super` in constructor of subclasses:

> Invocation of a superclass constructor must be the first line in the subclass constructor.

The syntax for calling a superclass constructor is

```
super();
```

or:

```
super(parameter list);
```

With `super()`, the superclass no-argument constructor is called. With `super(parameter list)`, the superclass constructor with a matching parameter list is called.

Note: *If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass*. If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error.

Related post:

[Polymorphism vs Overriding vs Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading/39532917#39532917)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it, commenting super(); does the same thing without commenting it as @Mark Peters said

```
package javaapplication6;

/**
 *
 * @author sborusu
 */
public class Super_Test {
    Super_Test(){
        System.out.println("This is super class, no object is created");
    }
}
class Super_sub extends Super_Test{
    Super_sub(){
       super();
       System.out.println("This is sub class, object is created");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Super_sub();
    }
}
```