# Should you use the superclass constructor to set variables?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, superclass

I somehow think that doing this is a bad idea. Is it common to do this? I'm unsure of it's usage because I've never seen it in practice, as a real world example anyway.

```
public abstract class Car{
    protected int speed;

    public Car(int speed){
        this.speed = speed;
    }
}

public class Ambulance extends Car{
    public Ambulance(int speed){
        super(speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually came across this question & answer later, which may be helpful to some: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090834/when-do-i-use-super-in-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a **standard practice** to use the superclass constructor. It allows code reuse, when some validations on the variables might have been done in the superclass constructor.

As an example, check [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.0/org/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack.java#ArrayStack.%3Cinit%3E%28int%29) code from Apache Commons Collection.

When used, `super(..)` must be the first statement within the child class constructor.

Comment: Perhaps "bad" was the wrong word to use, but since I've never seen it in actual use before I was wondering if I should really use it over regular setting. Thanks, the example is clear and logical too :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    protected int numWheels;
    protected int speed;

    public Vehicle() {
        this.speed = 0;
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {
     public Car() {
         super();
         this.numWheels = 4;
     }
}
```

All vehicles have a speed, which is defaulted to 0, but only car's have 4 wheels.

Answer (score 0):

For inheritence it's absolutly necessary. This is the reason, why abstract classes with different Constructers force you to implement all of them