# Why use super call in a super class when it has no explicitly defined super class

Tags: java, class, super

```
package Geometry;

public abstract class GeometryFigures{

protected double surfaces;
protected double perimeter;

public GeometryFigures(double surfaces, double perimeter) {

    super(); //**<---Why use super call here?**

    this.surfaces= surfaces;
    this.perimeter= perimeter;
}

public double getSurfaces() {
    return surfaces;
}

public double getPerimetre() {
    return perimeter;
}


}
```

So basically everything is in the title. I want to know why i'd need to use the super() in a super class.

Thx for the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090834/when-do-i-use-super-in-java

Comment: its not realy the same question here.. actually i know when i need to use super call but i wasn't sure why this code was calling a super constructor if is it in the super class.

Comment: Do you mean: "when it has no explicitly defined super class"? If yes, then your question is not that clear about it.

Comment: Yes that was i meant. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.

[according to docs.oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Answer (score 5):

In this case super() refers to the constructor of Object, which is every class' Superclass.

You don't actually need to call it though, since by default a constructor always tries to call super() if no other superclass constructor is called.

I've seen some code generators add it automatically, my guess is that it is considered a best practice as an explicit reminder that super() will be called.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to, because it will be added implicitly for you by the compiler.

I think IDEs add it automatically for you because they generate code based on templates. This could be helpful if `super` constructor requires some arguments that could be extracted locally.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have this class:

```
public class A {
   public A() {
       // N lines of code
   }
}
```

And then you have two child classes:

```
public class B extends A {
   public B() {
       // N lines of code
       // M lines of specific code for class B
   }
}

public class C extends A {
   public C() {
       // N lines of code
       // P lines of specific code for class C
   }
}
```

As you can note, since `B` and `C` classes inherit from `A`, you have to inherit the code of the constructor too. So, if you couldn't use `super()`, you would have to copy-paste all the code in every child class. And so on...

It also implies a certain level of abstraction when you extend some class, since the superclass may have certain code in its constructor, such as initializations.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there is no reason to use `super()`.  Java will automatically make that call for you even if you don't explicitly write it.

So when do you need to call `super()`?  Here's an example, using a *subclass* of your `GeometryFigures` class.

```
public class MyFigure extends GeometryFigures {

    public MyFigure() {
        super( 5.0, 42.0 );
    }

    // ...
}
```

Here you *need* a call to `super()` because there is no default (no argument) constructor in your class.  Java will not supply a call to `super()` that has arguments (how could it?  What parameters would it use?).  So in this case you must supply a call, and specify which constructor and which parameters to use.