# use super () in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to learn java oop and i find some problem understanding the use of super method when i make some exemple . Please chek the code below .

can you please tell me why the super(); method doesn't refer to the superClass ? i don't understand .

superClass :

```
package javaapplication;

public class A {

    protected String val;

    public A(){

        this.val = " Class A ";
    }
}
```

subClass

```
package javaapplication;


public class B extends A {


    public B(){

         this.val = " Class B";
         System.out.println(super.val);


    }
}
```

Main Class

```
package javaapplication;

public class JavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        B a = new B();


    }

}
```

output : run :  Class B

why i got "Class B" ?

Comment: Because you assign it to `Class B` in the `B` constructor? What did you expect? `val` is the same thing in both classes.

Comment: what did you expect as output ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do I use super()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090834/when-do-i-use-super)

Comment: super.methodA() behaves differently than super.variableA. *there is no overridding for variables, and hence a single copy*

Answer (score 7):

Because there is only one `val` variable, and your `B` constructor is setting it to " Class B".

You can use `super.something` to refer to `something` (member variable or method) on the superclass instead of the current class, but those will only be different if both classes declare `something`.  In this case, both `A` and `B` are sharing the `val` defined by `A`.

Answer (score 1):

A constructor in Java (now focus on your constructor of class B) ALWAYS calls either another constructor of class B if you explicitly tell you to do so with `this(arguments...)` or a constructor of the super class A if you explicitly tell you to do so with `super(arguments...)` or if you don't specify any call to another constructor it calls `super()`. And this call is the first instruction of any constructor. Unless the class you are talking about is Object.

So first the A constructor is called, setting val to "Class A" but then the constructor of class B continuous erasing that value and replacing it with "Class B".

Albeit a good example on how constructors work but in essence bad programming as this is not what you would do. A good programmer would add a contstructor in class A accepting the value for val and in class B you would call it using super("Class B") and val would be a private variable defined in class A.

Note that because class B extends class A, any instance of class B has the attributes defined in class B and class A, so super.val or this.val is doing referencing exactly the same variable. One could add a new variable val in class B but again this would be bad programming, if the compiler would accept this, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

when you do`B a = new B();` constructor of B is executed which internally call base class constructor as the first operation.So this sets the value of variable val as `Class A`. But then you are manually doing `this.val =  Class B` which sets the value again as `Class B`

Just comment out `this.val = Class B` from constructor B, it will print `Class A`