# Is Powershell Polymorphic?

Tags: oop, powershell, polymorphism

I would like to write some functions that take a single parameter which could vary the type without having to use a whole new function.

For instance for SQL, I would like to either accept sql command text string or a file. 
or for active directory either the path or the adsi object would be taken

`unlock-aduser [adsi]"LDAP://dn=..."`
or 
`unlock-aduser [string]"LDAP://dn=..."`

would work just as well.

Comment: For the record, I'd say this is not polymorphism but function overloading.

Comment: @J.N function overloading comes under polymorphism...

Comment: Not by everybody's definition. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading/154675#154675. I think not because when you use overloading the behavior is the same, but the inputs are different, while when you use polymorphism you tend to have the same inputs but a different behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply  **No** its not.

However you should take [a look here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/12/23/powershell-v2-parametersets.aspx) for parametersets

Answer (score 2):

The Powershell classes in V5 are poloymorphic

http://alexiscoles.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/polymorphism-powershell-v5-classes.html