# Does a method call call the class type or instance type?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have two classes: A and B, and B is a subclass of A (B extends A). Class A contains the method: doSomething(), and class B overrides this method with doSomething(). If I declare A variable = new B(); and then I call variable.doSomething(), which class will it reference?

```java
class A {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("classA");
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("classB");
    }
}

A variable = new B();
variable.doSomething();
//Will this print "classA or classB"?
```

Comment: It will print `classB`, but honestly why can't you just try this yourself?  You would learn a lot more about Java by exploring the code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That is a good point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a subclass method from superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021603/calling-a-subclass-method-from-superclass)

Comment: This is called polymorphism and is one of the basic concepts of OOP. It is a good question, but has been asked a million times before. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962364/example-of-polymorphism-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [example of polymorphism in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962364/example-of-polymorphism-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

When an overridden method is called through a superclass reference, Java determines which version of that method to execute based upon the type of the object being referred to at the time the call occurs. Thus, this determination is made at run time.

**It is the type of the object being referred to (not the type of the reference variable) that determines which version of an overridden method will be executed.**

```
A variable = new B();
variable.doSomething();
// Output: classB
```