# Polymorphism vs Inheritance

Tags: java, polymorphism

Suppose I have two classes: Animal and Dog. Dog is a subclass of Animal. I do the following code:

```
Animal a = new Dog();
```

Now I can call methods of the Dog class through the a variable.

But my question is this: if I can call all of Animal's methods through the Dog objects (inheritance) than why should I use the polymorphism principle? I can just declare:

```
Dog d = new Dog();
```

With this declaration can use all of Animal's methods and Dog methods. So why use polymorphism? Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: The question's title ("Polymorphism vs Inheritance") is wrong by definition :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the main difference between Inheritance and Polymorphism?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308178/what-is-the-main-difference-between-inheritance-and-polymorphism)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Java, the concepts of polymorphism and inheritance are "welded together"; in general, it does not have to be that way:

- Polymorphism lets you call methods of a class without knowing the exact type of the class
- Inheritance lets derived classes share interfaces and code of their base classes

There are languages where inheritance is decoupled from polymorphism:

- In C++ you can inherit a class without producing polymorphic behavior (i.e. do not mark functions in the base class with `virtual`)
- In Objective C you can implement a method on an unrelated class, and call it from a place that knows only the signature of the method.

Going back to Java, the reason to use polymorphism is decoupling your code from the details of the implementation of its counter-parties: for example, if you can write a method `Feed(Animal animal)` that works for all sorts of animals, the method would remain applicable when you add more subclasses or implementations of the `Animal`. This is in contrast to a `Feed(Dog dog)` method, that would be tightly coupled to dogs.

As far as the

```
Dog d = new Dog();
```

declaration goes, there is no general reason to avoid this if you know that the rest of your method deals specifically with dogs. However, in many cases the later is not the case: for example, your class or your methods would often be insensitive to the exact implementation, for example

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

In cases like that, you can replace `new ArrayList<Integer>()` with `new LinkedList<Integer>()`, and *know* that your code is going to compile. In contrast, had your `numbers` list been declared as `ArrayList<Integer> numbers`, such switchover may not have been a certainty.

This is called "programming to an interface". There is a very good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/335858) on Stack Overflow explaining it.

Answer (score 5):

You can have other implementations of the `Animal` class, such as `Cat`.  Then you can say

```
Animal a = new Dog();
Animal b = new Cat();
```

You can call methods of the `Animal` class without caring which implementation it really is, and [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) will call the correct method.  E.g.

```
a.speak();  // "Woof"

b.speak();  // "Meow"
```

Really, it's not "Polymorphism vs Inheritance" but "Polymorphism using Inheritance".

Comment: First, thank you for the answer. But I still don't get why shouldn't I just declare a: Dog d=new Dog(); instead of using Animal a=new Dog();. I can still use all of Animal's methods, won't I?

Comment: If you need `Dog`-specific functionality, then by all means use `Dog d = new Dog()`.  Please see @NPE's answer about when you only need `Animal`-specific functionality.  That code would work for any implementation of `Animal`.

Answer (score 4):

Polymorphism allows you to write a method that works for any `Animal`:

```
public void pet(Animal animal) {
   ...
}
```

This method would accept `Dog`, `Cat`, etc, including subclasses of `Animal` that are yet to be written.

If the method were to take `Dog`, it would not work for `Cat` etc.

Comment: First, thank you for the answer. But I still don't get why shouldn't I just declare a: Dog d=new Dog(); instead of using Animal a=new Dog();. I can still use all of Animal's methods, won't I?

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that it will always be a dog there is no reason for it. You might aswell use *Dog d = new Dog();* as you described. But let's say you used a method instead of a constructor. The method returned an animal and you wouldn't know which implementation of animal you would get. You would still be able to use the same methods on the animal (even if it's a Dog, Elephant cat etc).

For extensibility purposes inheritance simplifies things. When you want to create an elephant or cat which also share some animal methods, You can easily get those by having animal as super class.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the question you've asked is more similar to Inheritance vs Composition :) More "real life" example of why it's good to use polymorphism is for example usage of strategy design pattern. You can have many TaxPolicy implementation: UsaTaxPolicy, CanadaTaxPolicy, EuTaxPolicy, etc. If you have method calculateFinalPrice, which have to also calculate tax, then you inject the proper implementation and good calculation is executed, no matter you've passed Usa, Canada or Eu implementation.

Answer (score 0):

inheritance is the dynamic polymorphism. I mean when you remove inheritance you can not override anymore.