# Is this example of Polymorphism wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, polymorphism

I'm trying to get my head around polymorphism, my understanding is that it means that you can have the same method across multiple classes and at runtime the correct version will be called based on the type of the object it's being invoked on.

This example below, states:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_polymorphism.htm

"Objective-C polymorphism means that a call to a member function will cause a different function to be executed depending on the type of object that invokes the function."

In the example both square and rectangle are subclasses of shape which both implement their own calculateArea method, I'm assuming it's this method that's being used to demonstrate the polymorphism concept. They call 'calculateArea' on a Square object and squares calculateArea method is called, then they call 'caculateArea on a Rectangle object and rectangles 'calculateArea method is called. It can't be that simple, surely this is obvious, square doesn't even know about rectangles 'calculateArea' which is in a completely different class so couldn't ever possibly be confused about which version of the method to use.

What am I missing?

Comment: it isn't wrong, but it is a little weak... more about interface/duck typing than polymorphism...

Comment: the sample is not wrong technically but the way how it would like to show the polymorphism is vastly poor, because the key method (in the sample) is not the `calculateArea` but the `printArea`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct, that example doesn't illustrate polymorphism. This is how they should've written the example.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
//PARENT CLASS FOR ALL THE SHAPES
@interface Shape : NSObject
{
    CGFloat area;
}
- (void)printArea;
- (void)calculateArea;
@end

@implementation Shape
- (void)printArea{
    NSLog(@"The area is %f", area);
}
- (void)calculateArea
{
    NSLog(@"Subclass should implement this %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
@end

@interface Square : Shape
{
    CGFloat length;
}
- (id)initWithSide:(CGFloat)side;
@end

@implementation Square

- (id)initWithSide:(CGFloat)side{
    length = side;
    return self;
}
- (void)calculateArea{
    area = length * length;
}
- (void)printArea{
    NSLog(@"The area of square is %f", area);
}
@end

@interface Rectangle : Shape
{
    CGFloat length;
    CGFloat breadth;
}
- (id)initWithLength:(CGFloat)rLength andBreadth:(CGFloat)rBreadth;
@end

@implementation Rectangle

- (id)initWithLength:(CGFloat)rLength andBreadth:(CGFloat)rBreadth{
    length = rLength;
    breadth = rBreadth;
    return self;
}
- (void)calculateArea{
    area = length * breadth;
}

@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    Shape *shape_s = [[Square alloc]initWithSide:10.0];
    [shape_s calculateArea]; //shape_s of type Shape, but calling calculateArea will call the
                             //method defined inside Square
    [shape_s printArea];     //printArea implemented inside Square class will be called

    Shape *shape_rect = [[Rectangle alloc]
    initWithLength:10.0 andBreadth:5.0];
    [shape_rect calculateArea]; //Even though shape_rect is type Shape, Rectangle's
                                //calculateArea will be called.
    [shape_rect printArea]; //printArea of Rectangle will be called.       
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, so it's kind of like a runtime thing. Although you've specified the type of the object as being a 'Shape' it's actually been initialised in memory as a subclass of Shape and at runtime, it's aware of this fact and so calls that particular subclasses version of a method.

Comment: **Shape** *shape_rect = [[**Rectangle** alloc] initWithLength:10.0 andBreadth:5.0]; // Even though the type of shape_rect is Shape, but Rectangle object is being allocated and stored in the variable shape_rect as you can see by this statement [**Rectangle** alloc]. That is the reason it is possible to call initWithLength:andBreadth method that is defined in Rectangle class. If we were to do this: **Shape** *shape_rect = [[**Shape** alloc] initWithLength:10.0 andBreadth:5.0]; then objective-c would've thrown an error message saying that method does not exist.

Comment: Perfect, thanks chuthan, it's actually pretty straight forward if explained properly!

Comment: May be in this example you can assign to the base class, but its not recommended to assign it to the base class. We may use id at times. I hope @chuthan20 belongs is from C++ and hence his example is motivated to assign to base class. Also there are multiple types of polymorphism and we need not assign it to the base class. See this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) for types of polymorphism. This link also suggest the usage of polymorphism. [link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Dynamic_Binding_and_Typing_with_the_id_Type)

Comment: I would not say the referred example is not correct... the key method is not the `calculateArea` but the `printArea`, and that demonstrates the polymorphism quote well. on other hand, I agree that it is a very poor choice of representation of the polymorphism.

Comment: This answer copied from this link "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_polymorphism.htm"

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the tutorials point example, printArea(this explains about polymorphism) is called based on availability of method in based or derived class. Actually calculateArea is independent methods specific to the Rectangle and Square and calculateArea doesn't explain about polymorphism. Its misunderstood by you. Also you cannot call the calculateArea method if you create an object of type Shape since it don't have a method calculateArea.

Checkout the correct answer in this post that explains about polymorphism. 
[What is the main difference between Inheritance and Polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308178/what-is-the-main-difference-between-inheritance-and-polymorphism)