# Java generics and polymorphism

Tags: java

What is polymorphism in java? I am trying to understand this with generics.
Let us consider the following class Pair.

```
public class Pair<X, Y>
{ 
      public final X x; 
      public final Y y; 

      public Pair(X x, Y y) { 
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y; 
      } 
}
```

If we want to instantiate the class then we are doing to do something like this:

```
Pair <String, int> pair = new Pair<>("one", 1);
```

Now because i am using String and int instead of X and Y can i say this is polymorphism? There is also this concept of super classes and polymorphism. What about that?

Comment: That's not polymorphism at all. What you're seeing here is just plain generics.

Comment: Find a good book or article that will explain these concepts in much more depth than SO can.

Comment: Consider an abstract Animal class that has a method talk() and two concrete implementations like Dog and Cat which implement its own version of talk in the form that they return "Woof" or "Miau". Polimorphism is when you assign an Animal variable an instance of either of these classes. If you assigned a Cat instance to that variable and invoke talk() you'll receive a "Miau" while for a Dog instance you'll receive "Woof" without having to really know what concrete instance the Animal variable currently holds.

Comment: What you'd see there is a compiler error. You'd have to use `Integer` rather than `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Generics

What you see here are **generics**. It has nothing to do with polymorphism.

Generics are something like an argument is for a method:

```
public static void foo(int bar) { ... }
```

The method `foo` wants a user to give it some `int` value when it is called. The method itself refers to that value by the local variable `bar`. A call might look like

```
foo(5);
foo(8);
```

If you have a generic class like

```
public class Pair<A, B> { ... }
```

the class `Pair` wants the user to declare two types when using it. The class refers to them by the placeholders `A` and `B`. So one might use it like:

```
Pair<String, Integer> stringAndInteger;
Pair<Dog, Car> dogAndCar;
```

---

The nice thing about it is that the compiler can use this information to ensure that `dogAndCar` can really only be used with `Dog` and `Car` for `A` and `B`. So if the class has a method like

```
public void setFirst(A first) { ... }
```

you can not call the method with the wrong type, like `dogAndCar.setFirst(10);`. The compiler knows `A` is `Dog` for `dogAndCar` and will not allow that you use it with anything that is not `Dog`.

For more on the topic, read the [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) for generics.

---

### Polymorphism

Polymorphism refers to the concept of one class implementing features of a parent class but overriding some other or adding new functionality.

Let's consider the following parent class

```
public class Animal {
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Now we extend that class and override the method. Additionally we add a second method:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("wuff wuff");
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "John";
    }
}
```

If we use the `makeNoise` method on a `Dog`, we will see `"wuff wuff"` and not `"Hello"`.

For more on this take a look at the [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) on polymorphism.

Note that you can further distinguish this into **inheritance** and **polymorphism**. Read [What is the main difference between Inheritance and Polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308178/what-is-the-main-difference-between-inheritance-and-polymorphism) for more.

Comment: Incorrect, Generics are called "Parametric Polymorphism"

Comment: Feel free to propose an edit, thank you.