# Implementation of Abstract Data Types

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, nodes, abstract-data-type

I'm learning java and Abstract Data Types and I'm getting a little bit confused.

Basically, from what I understood, Abstract Data Types are something that is defined, but not implemented. So we have the API of the Abstract Data Type and we need to implement those methods specified in the API. For example, we have a Stack and we can implement it by using arrays, nodes, etc...
As an example, to declare those objects we do:

Stack ex = new ArrayStack<>(); or Stack ex = new NodeStack<>();

My problem is, we can also do Stack ex = new Stack<>(); without implementing anything. In this case which implementation are we using? What's the point of implementing it then? Can we choose which implementation we are going to use without implementing it ourselves? I'm so lost.

Another example, why do we need to create nodes to implement ADTs if we can use a LinkedList directly? Is it for leaning purposes only or are they something different?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: As sidenote, maybe this will help explain Polymorphism ("extend") vs interface: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308178/what-is-the-main-difference-between-inheritance-and-polymorphism

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in your description of an abstract data type. However if you are referring to `java.util.Stack<E>`, it isn't abstract and you can check the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).

---

**Edit**

A `LinkedList<E>` is also not abstract, but is an implementation of the `List<E>` interface. The `Node<E>` class is just used in the `LinkedList<E>` implementation. Apart from for learning purposes or using a `Node` style structure elsewhere, there is no need to create your own version.

Comment: My confusion is, if it is not abstract how do we know what implementation does it use to create the stack? Isn't there a perfect implementation for each scenario? Don't we have to choose an implementation according to the scenario?

Comment: There is only one implementation of the particular `java.util.Stack` class? Sorry I am not sure I quite understand your question

Comment: It's ok, thanks anyway for trying to help. So basically the java.util.Stack is not the implementation of the Stack API?

Comment: What do you mean by the Stack API?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it. I thought the stack was an ADT and java.util.Stack was one of his implementations(?). Thank you very much!

Comment: To be frank, `java.util.Stack` is a terrible example for figuring out ADTs vs implementations since it's inheritance-run-wild and there isn't a separate interface. A better example in the standard library is `java.util.Map` (the ADT) vs `java.util.HashMap` (an implementation).

Comment: Ah no, not the case. I would recommend following the advice of @KenWayneVanderLinde though, either with `Map` and `HashMap` or `List` and `ArrayList`.

Comment: Edited my answer!

Comment: Thanks for the time spent! Have a great day