# What is the difference between extends and override?

Tags: oop, inheritance, overriding

What is the difference between

```
extends(inheritance)
```

and

```
override(polymorphism)
```

?

Comment: Check out this discussion for further reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading

Comment: Also this seems to be an accurate distinction http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_inheritance_and_polymorphism

Comment: Don't get why this was downvoted. Although it may be a elementary question it was clear and to the point. +1 to offset the ridiculous downvote.

Comment: @inium : Inheritance supports class level reuse of existing code.... Overriding supports method level modification with the same signature....

Is Inheritance doesn't support method modification?

Comment: @Ascension Systems: Thanks for your care.
|
 I am novice to as3, that's y making elementary questions something like this.

Comment: No problem, it wasn't meant as an insult (saying elementary). When I started working in flash I just started out in programming and didn't know the first thing. In fact when I went for my first job interview as a flash developer I didn't even know the key concepts of OOP. lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extends: we create a new class(Inherited class) with the features of Existing (class Base class) and some additional features. This comes in picture in case of inheritance.

Example: NokiaBasic Handset.
         NokiaNSeries(Extends the features of NokiaBasic Handset features)

Overriding: comes to picture when functionality changes in the derived class. We override the functionality of a particular function in a derived class(Dynamic Polymorphism).

Example: All the functionality which NokiaBasicHandset has, are implemented in NokiaNSeries but there is a difference in the way we operate. (Picking a call, sending a message, sharing a file, etc.)

Comment: You have explained in a simple way... Gr8.. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

- **Extends** is about classes. This keyword represents the process of
  deriving a subclass from a base class.
- **Overriding** is about methods declaration and invocation. It means to
  define a method  in a subclass with the same signature of a method
  previously declared in its base class.

Answer (score 2):

Extends: you're inheriting all the functionality of the object you are inheriting from
Override: you're changing/adding to the functionality of something you have inherited