# How to - correctly - delegate the Class prototype

Tags: javascript, class, oop

If you jump to first Answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642239/what-is-polymorphism-in-javascript) you'll see that he used `Employee.prototype = new Person();` to inherit the `Person.prototype` to `Employee.prototype`, But When I learned about JavaScript OOP Course from Udacity they used `Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);`
instead.
What's the correct one :

```
Employee.prototype = new Person();
```

or

```
Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

or

```
Employee.prototype = Person.prototype;
```

If this question is duplicated please refer me some good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);` is the cleanest.

With `Employee.prototype = new Person();` you'll find that assignments to `this` in `Person` affect all of your `Employee` instances. Perhaps you don't want that. There could be other side effects, too.

For example (using some ES2015 syntax):

```
function Person(name = "fred") {
  this.name = name;
}

function Employee(...args) {
  Person.call(this, ...args);
}

Employee.prototype = new Person();


var e1 = new Employee();
console.log(e1.name); // fred
```

You need to read the `Person` code to understand why all of your employees are called `fred` by default. That's trivial in this case, but in the real world a lot of functions are long and stateful and easy to mis-read.

Imagine if `Person` depended on some outside state. The value of `Employee.prototype` could change based on whether or not some other code has already executed. You don't want that kind of uncertainty in your prototype chain.

For example:

```
let personCount = 0;
function Person() {
  this.id = personCount ++;
}

// ...

Employee.prototype = new Person();
// what `id` do Employees inherit? we don't know!
// it depend on how many times `Person` has been called,
//  and by creating `Employee.prototype` we changed the state even further. Uhoh.
```

`Object.create(Person.prototype)` is easier to reason about because there are no user function calls; there is no logic. You only need to check the static `Person.prototype` to see what you're inheriting.

It is still possible for prototypes to have mutable values, and therefore some uncertainty, but the act of *creating an object* itself doesn't have side effects so this kind of bug is less likely.

With `Employee.prototype = Person.prototype;`, changes to `Employee.prototype` will affect all `Person` instances. You probably don't want that.