# javascript, polymorphic new Myclass()?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I have many classes that has the following form.

```
static defaultInstance() {

 if (!defaultInstance) {
   defaultInstance = new Child1()
 }
 return defaultInstance
}
```

Since they have a common base class, I wanted to add the common function to the base class, but don't know how.
(having trouble with new Child1())

Comment: have you tried looking at this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642239/what-is-polymorphism-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Child1` is supposed to refer to the "current" class, i.e. the class that `defaultInstance` is invoked on, then you can just do

```
defaultInstance = new this();
```

This follows the normal JavaScript rules: If you invoke the function with `Child1.defaultInstance()`, then `this` refers to `Child1`.

**However**, this probably doesn't do what you want. If you define `defaultInstance` on the base class, then all child classes share *the same* `defaultInstance` variable.

If you want to have an instance *per* class, then each class needs its own `defaultInstance` method, or you need to use a property instead, e.g.

```
if (!this.__defaultInstance) {
  this.__defaultInstance = new this();
}
```

Comment: Any reason not to use a `Map` instead of `__defaultInstance`? Also that would need to be `this.hasOwnProperty('__defaultInstance')` or the class inheritance could break it.

Comment: You mean a `class name -> instance` map? That would work too. Or maybe a `WeakMap`.

Comment: e.g. `map.set(this, new this());`. Good call that WeakMap probably makes more sense, though unless you're dynamically declaring subclasses, the Map will probably be relatively static.

Comment: Your description of my problem is very correct, I'm a bit lost on the solution part though, `__defaultInstance` is a static member variable and each class has its own __defaultInstance ? I guess `map` variable could live in someplace where all classes can access/share.

Comment: *"each class has its own __defaultInstance"* Yes. *"I guess map variable could live in someplace where all classes can access/share."* That could just exist in the bas class file.