# Polymorphism in oop

Tags: java, oop

Are **method overloading** and **method overriding** justify as a example of oops Polymorphism ?, As there is nothing about object polymorphism in overloading and overriding.

(May be overriding somehow connect with object but overloading has nothing with object)

Comment: Is this Q specific to java or c++? It is tagged `java` but looks more c++ish.

Comment: Java doesn't have operator overloading.
 Did you mean method overloading, overriding and hiding ?

Comment: thanks Yochai Timmer for your correction.
@Als this is common oop concept question but put with java (As I am java programmer).

Comment: Similar question: [Polymorphism vs Overriding vs Overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading). BTW, it is **OOP** and not **OOPs**!

Answer (score 0):

Method overloading: An object may behave differently (for the same operation it has been called for), depending on: 
1. Its data (fields, properties)
2. Non class Property parameters
It does not seem to change its shape (polymorphisms) in such cases.

Method overriding: An object may behave as itself (method called in its own class), or it may behave as the Parent class. In the later case the object changes itself to its parent.
Hence, we see that overriding has everything to do with polymorphism