# "Polymorphism applies to overriding, not to overloading"?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I just read this line in book "Sun Certified Java Programmer" (page number-158) by **Kathy Sierra and Bert Bates** who worked as Master trainer at "Sun microsystems":

> Polymorphism applies to overriding, not to overloading.

But some other books and articles say overloading is also a form of polymorphism.. i'm confused.. Please help..

Comment: Don't believe the other books. Late binding (with overriden/inherited methods) is polymorphism. Static binding is what applies to overloading.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't believe the other books. **Late binding** ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding#Late_binding_in_Java)) (with overriden/inherited methods) is polymorphism. **Static binding** is what applies to overloading.

The two **bolded** expressions are concepts you should familiarize yourself with as soon as possible. There are a number of available resources. [Maybe start here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ca/2012/03/what-is-static-and-dynamic-binding-in.html).