# Enforce method overload

Tags: java, polymorphism

Looking at great example [Polymorphism vs Overriding vs Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154577/2323086) , consider this scenario:

```
abstract class Human {

  public void goPee() {
    println("drop pants");
  }
}

class Male extends Human {

  public void goPee() {
    super.goPee();
    println("stand up");
  }
}

class Female extends Human {
  public void goPee() {
    super.goPee();
    println("sit down");
  }
}
```

My questions:

1. Is it possible, on concrete classes level, to **enforce** using super.goPee() inside goPee() ? if so - how ?
2. Is it possible, on abstract class level, to know which concrete class had called super.goPee() ? Rationale for that is if I would need to call method let's say `liftToiletSeat()` somewhere on abstract class level.

Thank you.

Comment: (talking about your example)

Comment: yes, particularly on my first question.

Comment: you could argue that this is the childs class responsibility. If the child class just doesn't want any hassle, sure, call the parents class which should be enough for everyone. I would even go as far as saying your function shouldn't need anything more for it to be complete, but that is besides the point. Lets say another Human, `child` doesn't wear pants, so it has got its own way of peing. (just `println("make_a_mess");` I guess). (This class wouldn't want to call the parent. Or if it for some other reasons want to implement everything itself: why disallow that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enforce it by not giving the subclass a choice, by using a simple [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).  In the superclass that wants to enforce a call to `super`, don't give a choice.

Make the method `final` so it can't be overridden, and then call an `abstract protected` method that must be overridden.  The superclass behavior is enforced.

```
abstract class Human {

   public final void goPee() {
       System.out.println("drop pants");
       toStandOrNotToStand();
   }

   protected abstract void toStandOrNotToStand();
}
```

Then the subclass *can't* override the superclass method, so it can't decide not to call `super`, but it must override the abstract method to be concrete.

```
class Male extends Human {
    @Override
    protected void toStandOrNotToStand() {
        println("stand up");
    }
}
```

And `Female` can be done similarly.

It is possible to know the concrete class with the `getClass()` method, but it doesn't make sense to do subclass-specific behavior in a superclass.  You should be able to have `liftToiletSeat` in the `Male` subclass.