# get() method behavior in ArrayList() having raw type but no type parameter

Tags: java, generics, collections

I am working over Java collections.
I found something strange and not getting why is this happening.
So here is the scenario.

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
al.add("Hello World");
//The below line is creating some confusion
System.out.print(al.get(0));
```

Now the last line is printing "Hello World" as it is.
But as i am not using any type parameter it should give an object type in return.So it should call the Object's `toString()` instead of String's `toString()`.

Does it depend on the object type which is getting saved (like String here ) of the return type (like Object).
Please help.

Comment: I think you need to read up on how inheritance works. This has nothing to do with `ArrayList` it has to do with you not understanding the inheritance model.

Comment: You get the same effect if you did `Object obj = "Hello World"; System.out.println(obj);`.

Comment: Yes i know my bad, But if you can explain a bit or provide any link.That would be much helpful

Comment: In any case, don't ever use an raw-type without a type parameter.

Comment: @BoristheSpider It's naught to do with inheritance; it has to do with polymorphism (the same can be obtained in languages *without* inheritance or without subtype polymorphism).

Comment: @AnkitNigam tldr; the method called is `print(Object obj)` which in turn calls `obj.toString()` (if `obj` is not null) - it displays the result accordingly. Every object (including Strings) conforms to Object, as Object is a super-type of all Java objects, and thus has a `toString`. For a String *object*, `str.toString() == str` - that is, it returns itself. (Java uses runtime/sub-type polymorphism to execute the "right method" for the specific type.)

Comment: @user2864740 yes getting your point that every object confirms to Object as it is the parent class of every class.But as the return object by get(0) is of Object type , the method toString() should be called of Object type ?

Comment: @AnkitNigam Because of **runtime polymorphism** the method of the *actual* type of the object - not the type of the expression - is invoked. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading , etc.

Comment: @AnkitNigam it's not like that Ankit...there is no way we can call specific toString method out side String class....when you call toString() on an object you are ultimately calling the method overrided in toString(). The reference type doesn't matter...  String str="Hello"; Object obj=str; str.toString() and obj.toString() both call the toString() from String class because the actuall object we have created ("Hello") is of type String that's what matters but not the reference type of obj i.e., Object

Comment: @user2864740 ok I checked the link . So the return type of Object reference doesn't actually typecast the String Object stored at the 0 index but is actually only referring to the String Object.So toString() is actually called on String object.Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @AnkitNigam Any Java typecast is irrelevant here (there was an implicit upcast when assigning the String to the raw-type generic) as typecasts *do not* change the *type of the object*; they only change the *type of the expression*. (Except for autoboxing which is another mess.)

Comment: @pinkpanther so the reference type doesn't matter , what matters is the object type the reference is referring to.Am i right ?

Comment: @AnkitNigam The type of the expression only matters insofar as Java can find the right method/overload *signature* - not the implementation of such. This only applies to "virtual" methods.

Comment: Thankyou @user2864740 Sir. Things are getting clearer to me. One more query , that the code i wrote above , is there any chance i can call the method of Object class's toString()

Comment: @AnkitNigam Not if it is overridden by a super-type (in this case that is String.toString) of the final *object*.

Comment: @AnkitNigam yes...you are getting it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually all the trick is not related to generics even you snippet showcase it.

It related to **overriden** methods, `toString()` is defined in the super super class `Object` and overriden in the `String` class, that are evalutated at runtime using the actual **object type** and not its reference, i.e when calling:

```
Object o = new String("hello");
o.toString(); // Here at runtime, the JVM will call the "hello" toString method and not the Object one.
```

---

In you code, you have called:

```
al.add("Hello World");
```

The above line do the following:

- Creates a new `String` object with *Hello World* as a literal and add it to the string pool.
- Makes the first element in the list (element at index 0) reference that object (that is a String one).

Now when calling `System.out.print(al.get(0));`:

- The first element of the list, which is an `Object` reference to a `String` object, got his `toString()` method called and which as already said will evalute to the object real type and not the refence type, i.e. you will have `String#toString` method called.

Comment: Thanks @tmarwen for the detailed explanation.Now i have got the idea behind this.

Comment: @AnkitNigam, just rember that overriden methods are evaluted based on actual object type. Do not forget to accept the answer an upvote it to make it eligible for future visitors :)

Comment: yes I will remember it for sure.But i am not able to vote up.May be because i am a new user.

Comment: Yes you have to gain reputation to vote up and I will make sure to help you own some so you it will ease it for you in the future, but you still can accept the answer if you are quite satisfied with :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return `String`s from a collection you'll have to initialise it like this, using a `String` type parameter:

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
//       ^^^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^^^
al.add("Hello World");
String value = al.get(0);  //<-- now you can get Strings
```

Now, however you will only be able to get objects, and you will have to cast before getting back to your original type:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
al.add("Hello World");
Object object = al.get(0); //<-- ok
String value = (String)al.get(0); // <-- ok
value = al.get(0);  //<-- wont compile
```

**Edit**

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
al.add("Hello World");
Object object = al.get(0); //<-- ok
String value = object.toString();
```

In this case, calling `object.toString()`, will just return the object as a `String`. It will call the [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString()) method on the `String` class, which just returns itself.

Comment: My question is actually this :- Object object = al.get(0); what would happen if i do object.toString() . Will the Object class method or String clas  method toString() is called?

Comment: @AnkitNigam And that question can be reproduced as: `Object foo = "bar"; System.out.print(foo)` or even `System.out.print((Object)"bar")`.. Note that in this shorter reproduction the variable supplied as an argument *also* evaluates to a *String object* even though it is an *Object-typed expression*. Overriding (run-time polymorphism) depends on the *object*, overloading (compile-time polymorphism) depends on the *expression*.

Comment: @user2864740 yes, right you can reporduce it in this way also.SO can i conclude that the behavior of `foo` in the above code depens on the type of object it refers to ? like `String` inthis case ?

Comment: @AnkitNigam The difference between `print("bar")` and `print((Object)"bar")` is that they call a different overload: ie. `print(String str)` and `print(Object obj)`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html - The `toString` (used in `print(Object obj)`) is still based on run-time polymorphism; but `print(String str)` can skip that step because it already has a String (or null).

Answer (score 1):

When calling a method of an object, the actual method that is called is of the actual type of the object. This is why the toString that is actually called is the String class method.

BTW: generic types are for compile-time, and not for runtime. For example you can't have in the same class 2 methods like:
void foo(List l) and 
void foo(List l) since after compiling both have the same signature.