# Polymorphism examples in JDK

Tags: java

I am very intersted in Polymorphism and Inheritance in C++. I wonder if there is such examples in Java( note I am just beginnning to learn it, and I find it really hard to read from JDK documentation ) and what are the best examples of Polymorphism in Java(JDK Classes to look for )? Thanks.

Comment: Have you read [The Java Tutorials - Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)?

Comment: I did. But I wanted to know what Classes in JDK are bearers of Polymorphism so that I can take a look in the code and see how it is being processed. I know what Polymorphism is from C++, I just need to see how it is being handle in Java.

Comment: Look at class Number and its subclasses, Integer, Byte, Double, etc.  Java also has interfaces for polymorphism so look at CharSequence and is implementations -     CharBuffer, Segment, String, StringBuffer, StringBuilder

Comment: Swing has a huge hierarchy of objects.  You can start at [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) and just drill down.

Comment: See this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/154939/837765