# Java: Cannot override abstract method passing subclass

Tags: java, abstract-class, subclass, extend

I have an abstract class

```
public abstract class SuperclassA{
   public abstract void method(SuperclassB b);
}
```

And an implementation

```
public class SubclassA extends SuperclassA{

   @override
   public void method(SubclassB b){
   }
}
```

where `SubclassB extends SuperclassB`.

My NetBeans editor complains that I am not overriding `method`.
What can I do to actually pass a subclass to `method`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to override a method of the base class, the sub-class's method must have the same signature.

If you want the overridden method to accept only instances of `SubclassB`, you can test for it :

```
public class SubclassA extends SuperclassA
{
   @Override
   public void method(SuperclassB b){
       if (!(b instanceof SubclassB)) {
           // throw some exception
       }
       SubclassB sb = (SubclassB) b;
       ...
   }
}
```

You can call that method as follows :

```
SuperclassA a = new SubclassA ();
a.method (new SubclassB ());
```

Comment: With it be OK to use the following? Consider `A` an object of `SubclassA`:

`A.method(new SubclassB);`

Otherwise, how can I possibly pass an instance of `SuperclassB`, since it is `abstract`?

Comment: @ZzKr Yes, you can, assuming A is an instance of SubclassA .

Comment: @ZzKr See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html
An Instance child object can also be passed on as its patents type. Meaning you can use it in any situation where the parent class (up to Object) is called for.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the method signatures of a class or interface as a contract or a promise of what it and any subclass can do.

`SuperclassA` promises to do action `method` for any `SuperclassB`. In order for `SubclassA` to be a `SuperclassA` it must do action `method` for **all** `SuperclassB`. The issue is that it only does action `method` for **some** types of `SuperclassB`.

Here is the same situation with names that are easier to understand.

```
abstract class Pet {
    // Pet methods
}

class Cat extends Pet {
    // Cat methods
}

class Dog extends Pet {
    // Dog methods
}

abstract class PetShop {
    public abstract void groom(Pet pet);
}
```

The Pet shop class promises that any PetShop can groom any Pet, including dogs.

```
PetShop shop = new FranksPetShop();
shop.groom(new Dog());
```

If we define FranksPetShop like so it only defines how to groom Cat's, any other type of Pet (including dogs) is not defined.

```
class FranksPetShop {
    @Override
    public abstract void groom(Cat cat) {
        // Groom that cat
    }
}
```

To solve this FranksPetShop has to define how to groom a Pet not just a Cat.

```
class FranksPetShop {
    @Override
    public abstract void groom(Pet pet) {
        // Groom that pet
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Actual, Method Signature is,

```
public abstract void method(SuperclassB b);// into abstract class
```

> Your overrided Method Signature must be same,  Otherwise it's not
>   `override`, in fact it will be treated like `overloading`,

```
@override
   public void method(SuperclassB b){
   }

  //OverLoad not Override
   public void method(SubclassB b){
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method in `SubclassA` takes in a type of `SubclassB`. The method in `SuperclassA` is taking in a type of `SuperclassB`. You are not overriding the parent class method, you are overloading by using a different type.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you could try this

```
public class SubclassA extends SuperclassA{

   @override
   public void method(SuperclassB b){
   }
}
```

Which would override the method you want. As long as `SubclassB` is a child of `SuperclassB`, then you will still be able to pass `SubclassB` in.

You can still have an overloaded method that takes in `Subclasss` if you want.

```
public class SubclassA extends SuperclassA{

   @override
   public void method(SuperclassB b){
   }

   public void method(SubclassB b){
   }
}
```

Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading) for more info about overloading vs overriding.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to oracle documentation page on [override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).

> An instance method in a subclass with the same signature (name, plus the number and the type of its parameters) and return type as an instance method in the superclass overrides the superclass's method.

The ability of a subclass to override a method allows a class to inherit from a superclass whose behavior is "close enough" and then to modify behavior as needed.

> The overriding method has the same name, number and type of parameters, and return type as the method that it override

In your case, you did not use same method signature.

```
public void method(SubclassB b){
```

should be changed to

```
public void method(SuperclassB b){
```

Now you can use workaround suggested by Eran by using `instanceof`