# Why callback method is used for polymorphism

Tags: java, interface, callback

I have a callback interface.

```
public interface CallBack{
  void executeforConn();
}

abstract class CallbackImpl implements Callback {     
  void executeforConn(){
    executeStatements();
  }

  abstract void executeStatements();
}
```

In the caller the callback is called.

```
new CallbackImpl{
  @Override
  executeStatements(){
    //extend the method
  }
}

Callback callback = new CallbackImpl();
callback.executeforConn();
```

The caller calls the implementation of callback method. What I do not understand why is it called a callback method. I know by using interface you get the flexibility to register any class which implements CallBack with the Caller. It doesn't have to be just CallBackImpl.

Comment: You are missing the `execute` in your instantiation of `CallbackImpl`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polymorphism vs Overriding vs Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading)

Comment: My doubt is why it is called as callback

Comment: You can call it whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I do not understand why is it called a callback method.

It is called a "callback" because it allows the method that you passed the object to "call back" to your code.

For a more detailed explanation of the purpose  and use of callbacks, read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) on callbacks.

> Why callback method is used for polymorphism

A callback interface and (multiple) implementations could be viewed as a (rather uninteresting) example *of* polymorphism; e.g. one Callback API with multiple implementations that implement different behaviors.