# How does Polymorphism work in Java (Which method will be called??)

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

What will happen for the following statements in Java:

```
SuperclassObject o = new SubclassObject();
```

then we run

```
o.randomMethod();
```

However, `randomMethod()` has been implemented in both `SuperclassObject` and `SubclassObject`, but in different ways. Which method will be called??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polymorphism vs Overriding vs Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading)

Comment: Have you considered testing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading Try this.

Comment: What do you mean `in different ways`? Do you mean a different argument list, changed to a static function or something else? Changing it would almost certainly entail calling the function differently, so there couldn't be any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

It will call the subclass version. Why? Because there is only one concrete object in memory and that object belongs to the subclass.

Yes, the subclass can act as the superclass but in the inside it has only its own implementation of the method.

Comment: ...unless the method in question is static.