# Java Polymorphism Exercise

Tags: java, compiler-construction, polymorphism, runtime, late-binding

Can someone please explain how the compiler/runtime runs the
appropriate method in the example? 
There are 6 classes and a method `void m(/* ... */)` with different parameters.
I know that the compiler analyses the 
declared types.
The output is always "M" from the Middle class.

```
public class All {}
public class Most extends All {}
public class Special extends Most {}

public class Top {
    public void m( All p )     { System.out.println("A"); }
}
public class Middle extends Top {
    public void m( All p )     { System.out.println("M"); }
    public void m( Special p ) { System.out.println("L"); }
}
public class Bottom extends Middle {
    public void m( Most p ) { System.out.println("V"); }
    public void m( Special p ) { System.out.println("X"); }
}

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    All all = new All();
    Most most = new Most();
    Special special = new Special();

    Top x = new Middle();
    Top y = new Bottom();
    Middle z = new Bottom();

    x.m( most );     // Output is M
    x.m( special );  // Output is M
    y.m( all );      // Output is M
    y.m( special );  // Output is M
    z.m( all );      // Output is M
    z.m( most );     // Output is M
  }
}
```

Comment: What specifically don't you understand?

Comment: For example I didn't understand why the second call of m ->     x.m( special );   is not "L" , there is a method with parameter 'Special', but instead the method with the parameter with 'All' runs.

Comment: Because `x` is declared as `Top` and overloads are resolved at runtime.

Comment: A good example of polymorphism is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading

Comment: Oops, I meant to say compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method overriding is resolved at runtime, by looking at what the runtime type of the object. The compiler also decides which method to call, but it can only decide based on the compile time type of the expression.

For the two calls on `x`, they both resolve to `Top.m(All)` at compile time. `x` is of compile time type `Top`, so the compiler can only look for methods declared in `Top` and its superclasses. The compiler finds the only available method is `m(All)`. At runtime, the method to call is resolved to `Middle.m(All)`. This is because the runtime type of `x` is actually `Middle`, so the runtime will call the overridden `m(All)`in `Middle`. Why didn't it call `Middle.m(Special)`? The compiler has already decided that `Top.m(All)` should be called. The runtime will only check if the runtime type has overridden that. The compiler does not know there is a `Middle.m(Special)` because `x` is of compile time type `Top`.

The two calls on `y` is similar. `y`'s compile time type is still `Top`, so the compiler resolves the method to be `Top.m(All)`. `y` is of runtime type `Bottom`. Since `Bottom` inherits from `Middle`, it also overrides `Top.m(All)`. The implementation is the same as in `Middle`. The overridden method is thus called at runtime.

The two calls on `z` is a bit different, but they still resolve to `Middle.m(All)` eventually. The compile time type of `z` is `Middle`, so both calls resolve to `Middle.m(All)`. Note that there is no `Middle.m(Most)`, so the call `z.m(most)` will still resolve to `Middle.m(All)`. At runtime, the method is still resolved to `Middle.m(All)` because the runtime type `Bottom` does not override `Middle.m(All)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!